# Projecting to EPSG 4326, WGS 84 Yielding Different Results in QGIS, ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I am projecting a shapefile from "NAD 1983 2011 StatePlane New Hampshire FIPS 2800 Ft US" to "EPSG 4326, WGS 84." However, the result output by QGIS seems to differ by about 3.25 feet from the ArcMap output. The QGIS shapefile is also about 20% smaller in file size. I tried the same function in FME and it matches the QGIS output spatially, but has the same file size as the ArcMap output. I tried in Global Mapper and the output is about .001 feet North of what I get with QGIS and FME

Why don't these match up?

Figure below: Blue is ArcGIS and green is QGIS

Original Vertex: (1082696.828, 1021749.922 feet)

QGIS Vertex: (-71.28406755831366581, 45.30234233581942505)

ArcMAP Vertex:(-71.28406837515765915 45.3023515785411135)

[image]

Comment: what are you comparing it to?

Comment: I'm comparing the QGIS output to the ArcMap output. I'm comparing the polygons from the two shapefiles and they don't line up.

Comment: may be you need to add a screen shot

Comment: Coordinates of one source vertex as original and after conversion with QGIS and ArcMAP would be nice.

Comment: Your original vertex should have totally different values and feet as units.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Mixed that up. Original looks like it's in the same location as projected. I noticed when I load the original file in QGIS, it states CRS as " * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-71.66666666666667 +k=0.9999666666666667 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs)"

Comment: When I unproject the point in the Esri projection engine, I'm closer to the QGIS results. Is there a geographic (datum) transformation set in ArcMap?

Comment: In ArcMap, WGS_1984_(ITRF08)_To_NAD_1983_2011 is set by default under Geographic Transformation when I perform the Projection.

Comment: Well, there's your difference. WGS84/ITRFxx are about 1 m from NAD83 2011. If you don't want the transformation, set it to none, or use 6318 (NAD 1983 (2011)) as the input GCS rather than WGS84. We don't have a WGS84/NAD83(2011) transformation that has its parameters set to zeroes. Another possible solution is to create a custom transformation.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it won't let me take the transformation out for whatever reason. I guess that's the difference between the QGIS and ArcGIS projection in this case. Projecting to 6318 in ArcGIS seems to give the same results as projecting to 4326 in QGIS or FME. Thanks for the help in identifying the disparity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projecting to EPSG 4326, WGS 84 in ArcMap 10.5 seems to require a transformation. In ArcGIS Pro 1.4 or QGIS 2.18.3, a transformation is not required to project to EPSG 4326, WGS 84. The difference in projecting to EPSG 4326, WGS 84 in ArcGIS Pro vs QGIS seems to be about 1/10,000 of an inch.